# Why do we use __init__ in Python classes?

Tags: python, class

I am having trouble understanding the Initialization of classes.

What's the point of them and how do we know what to include in them? Does writing in classes require a different type of thinking versus creating functions (I figured I could just create functions and then just wrap them in a class so I can re-use them. Will that work?)

Here's an example:

```
class crawler:
  # Initialize the crawler with the name of database
  def __init__(self,dbname):
    self.con=sqlite.connect(dbname)

  def __del__(self):
    self.con.close()

  def dbcommit(self):
    self.con.commit()
```

Or another code sample:

```
class bicluster:
  def __init__(self,vec,left=None,right=None,distance=0.0,id=None):
    self.left=left
    self.right=right
    self.vec=vec
    self.id=id
    self.distance=distance
```

There are so many classes with `__init__` I come across when trying to read other people's code, but I don't understand the logic in creating them.

Comment: the story of __init__ is... blah, blah, blah.... constructor-destructor but no destructor because garbage collection available.

Answer (score 325, accepted):

By what you wrote, you are missing a critical piece of understanding: the difference between a class and an object. `__init__` doesn't initialize a class, it initializes an instance of a class or an object. Each dog has colour, but dogs as a class don't. Each dog has four or fewer feet, but the class of dogs doesn't. The class is a concept of an object. When you see Fido and Spot, you recognise their similarity, their doghood. That's the class.

When you say

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self, legs, colour):
        self.legs = legs
        self.colour = colour

fido = Dog(4, "brown")
spot = Dog(3, "mostly yellow")
```

You're saying, Fido is a brown dog with 4 legs while Spot is a bit of a cripple and is mostly yellow. The `__init__` function is called a constructor, or initializer, and is automatically called when you create a new instance of a class. Within that function, the newly created object is assigned to the parameter `self`. The notation `self.legs` is an attribute called `legs` of the object in the variable `self`. Attributes are kind of like variables, but they describe the state of an object, or particular actions (functions) available to the object.

However, notice that you don't set `colour` for the doghood itself - it's an abstract concept. There are attributes that make sense on classes. For instance, `population_size` is one such - it doesn't make sense to count the Fido because Fido is always one. It does make sense to count dogs. Let us say there're 200 million dogs in the world. It's the property of the Dog class. Fido has nothing to do with the number 200 million, nor does Spot. It's called a "class attribute", as opposed to "instance attributes" that are `colour` or `legs` above.

Now, to something less canine and more programming-related. As I write below, class to add things is not sensible - what is it a class of? Classes in Python make up of collections of different data, that behave similarly. Class of dogs consists of Fido and Spot and 199999999998 other animals similar to them, all of them peeing on lampposts. What does the class for adding things consist of? By what data inherent to them do they differ? And what actions do they share?

However, numbers... those are more interesting subjects. Say, Integers. There's a lot of them, a lot more than dogs. I know that Python already has integers, but let's play dumb and "implement" them again (by cheating and using Python's integers).

So, Integers are a class. They have some data (value), and some behaviours ("add me to this other number"). Let's show this:

```
class MyInteger:
    def __init__(self, newvalue):
        # imagine self as an index card.
        # under the heading of "value", we will write
        # the contents of the variable newvalue.
        self.value = newvalue
    def add(self, other):
        # when an integer wants to add itself to another integer,
        # we'll take their values and add them together,
        # then make a new integer with the result value.
        return MyInteger(self.value + other.value)

three = MyInteger(3)
# three now contains an object of class MyInteger
# three.value is now 3
five = MyInteger(5)
# five now contains an object of class MyInteger
# five.value is now 5
eight = three.add(five)
# here, we invoked the three's behaviour of adding another integer
# now, eight.value is three.value + five.value = 3 + 5 = 8
print eight.value
# ==> 8
```

This is a bit fragile (we're assuming `other` will be a MyInteger), but we'll ignore now. In real code, we wouldn't; we'd test it to make sure, and maybe even coerce it ("you're not an integer? by golly, you have 10 nanoseconds to become one! 9... 8....")

We could even define fractions. Fractions also know how to add themselves.

```
class MyFraction:
    def __init__(self, newnumerator, newdenominator):
        self.numerator = newnumerator
        self.denominator = newdenominator
        # because every fraction is described by these two things
    def add(self, other):
        newdenominator = self.denominator * other.denominator
        newnumerator = self.numerator * other.denominator + self.denominator * other.numerator
        return MyFraction(newnumerator, newdenominator)
```

There's even more fractions than integers (not really, but computers don't know that). Let's make two:

```
half = MyFraction(1, 2)
third = MyFraction(1, 3)
five_sixths = half.add(third)
print five_sixths.numerator
# ==> 5
print five_sixths.denominator
# ==> 6
```

You're not actually declaring anything here. Attributes are like a new kind of variable. Normal variables only have one value. Let us say you write `colour = "grey"`. You can't have another variable named `colour` that is `"fuchsia"` - not in the same place in the code.

Arrays solve that to a degree. If you say `colour = ["grey", "fuchsia"]`, you have stacked two colours into the variable, but you distinguish them by their position (0, or 1, in this case).

Attributes are variables that are bound to an object. Like with arrays, we can have plenty `colour` variables, *on different dogs*. So, `fido.colour` is one variable, but `spot.colour` is another. The first one is bound to the object within the variable `fido`; the second, `spot`. Now, when you call `Dog(4, "brown")`, or `three.add(five)`, there will always be an invisible parameter, which will be assigned to the dangling extra one at the front of the parameter list. It is conventionally called `self`, and will get the value of the object in front of the dot. Thus, within the Dog's `__init__` (constructor), `self` will be whatever the new Dog will turn out to be; within `MyInteger`'s `add`, `self` will be bound to the object in the variable `three`. Thus, `three.value` will be the same variable outside the `add`, as `self.value` within the `add`.

If I say `the_mangy_one = fido`, I will start referring to the object known as `fido` with yet another name. From now on, `fido.colour` is exactly the same variable as `the_mangy_one.colour`.

So, the things inside the `__init__`. You can think of them as noting things into the Dog's birth certificate. `colour` by itself is a random variable, could contain anything. `fido.colour` or `self.colour` is like a form field on the Dog's identity sheet; and `__init__` is the clerk filling it out for the first time.

Any clearer?

**EDIT**: Expanding on the comment below:

You mean a list of **objects**, don't you?

First of all, `fido` is actually not an object. It is a variable, which is currently containing an object, just like when you say `x = 5`, `x` is a variable currently containing the number five. If you later change your mind, you can do `fido = Cat(4, "pleasing")` (as long as you've created a class `Cat`), and `fido` would from then on "contain" a cat object. If you do `fido = x`, it will then contain the number five, and not an animal object at all.

A class by itself doesn't know its instances unless you specifically write code to keep track of them. For instance:

```
class Cat:
    census = [] #define census array

    def __init__(self, legs, colour):
        self.colour = colour
        self.legs = legs
        Cat.census.append(self)
```

Here, `census` is a class-level attribute of `Cat` class.

```
fluffy = Cat(4, "white")
spark = Cat(4, "fiery")
Cat.census
# ==> [<__main__.Cat instance at 0x108982cb0>, <__main__.Cat instance at 0x108982e18>]
# or something like that
```

Note that you won't get `[fluffy, sparky]`. Those are just variable names. If you want cats themselves to have names, you have to make a separate attribute for the name, and then override the `__str__` method to return this name. This method's (i.e. class-bound function, just like `add` or `__init__`) purpose is to describe how to convert the object to a string, like when you print it out.

Comment: wow thanks..this actually made alot of sense to me so anything that makes something what it is, I need to pre-declare in the init function.  In this case, Dog, has legs and colour. For example, if I made a class that added two numbers, I would declare self.firstnumber and self.secondnumber then just do firstnumber + secondnumber later on in the class to get the answer?

Comment: Kind of. You could do that. But it hardly makes sense to make a class just to add things. Classes normally implement data with behaviours - pure behaviours are just functions. I'll expand the answer with something relevant; wait a bit.

Comment: Thank you for the amazing answer. I see and understand the power of classes now. Sorry, if it sounds dumb.  You just me realize I can sort data and maintain the state of many different things at once(whereas I would only track as many variables as I can create or more via loops).  So say, I need to figure out the average number of legs per dog?  Is there a way to retrieve a list of all objects I have created with a class so I can start a calucation like this? or should I also be maintaining a list of the classes I create(i.e. [fido, spot])

Answer (score 29):

To contribute my 5 cents to the [thorough explanation from Amadan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8609238/3357935).

Where classes are a description "of a type" in an abstract way. Objects are their realizations: the living breathing thing. In the object-orientated world there are principal ideas you can almost call the essence of everything. They are:

1. encapsulation (won't elaborate on this)
2. inheritance
3. polymorphism

Objects have one, or more characteristics (= Attributes) and behaviors (= Methods). The behavior mostly depends on the characteristics.
Classes define what the behavior should accomplish in a general way, but as long as the class is not realized (instantiated) as an object it remains an abstract concept of a possibility.
 Let me illustrate with the help of "inheritance" and "polymorphism".

```
    class Human:
        gender
        nationality
        favorite_drink
        core_characteristic
        favorite_beverage
        name
        age

        def love    
        def drink
        def laugh
        def do_your_special_thing                

    class Americans(Humans)
        def drink(beverage):
            if beverage != favorite_drink: print "You call that a drink?"
            else: print "Great!" 

    class French(Humans)
        def drink(beverage, cheese):
            if beverage == favourite_drink and cheese == None: print "No cheese?" 
            elif beverage != favourite_drink and cheese == None: print "Révolution!"

    class Brazilian(Humans)
        def do_your_special_thing
            win_every_football_world_cup()

    class Germans(Humans)
        def drink(beverage):
            if favorite_drink != beverage: print "I need more beer"
            else: print "Lecker!" 

    class HighSchoolStudent(Americans):
        def __init__(self, name, age):
             self.name = name
             self.age = age

jeff = HighSchoolStudent(name, age):
hans = Germans()
ronaldo = Brazilian()
amelie = French()

for friends in [jeff, hans, ronaldo]:
    friends.laugh()
    friends.drink("cola")
    friends.do_your_special_thing()

print amelie.love(jeff)
>>> True
print ronaldo.love(hans)
>>> False
```

Some characteristics define human beings. But every nationality differs somewhat. So "national-types" are kinda Humans with extras. "Americans" are a type of "Humans " and inherit some abstract characteristics and behavior from the human type (base-class) : that's inheritance. So all Humans can laugh and drink, therefore all child-classes can also! Inheritance (2).

But because they are all of the same kind (Type/base-class : Humans) you can exchange them sometimes: see the for-loop at the end. But they will expose an individual characteristic, and thats Polymorphism (3).

So each human has a favorite_drink, but every nationality tend towards a special kind of drink.
If you subclass a nationality from the type of Humans you can overwrite the inherited behavior as I have demonstrated above with the `drink()` Method.
But that's still at the class-level and because of this it's still a generalization.

```
hans = German(favorite_drink = "Cola")
```

instantiates the class German and I "changed" a default characteristic at the beginning.
(But if you call hans.drink('Milk') he would still print "I need more beer" - an obvious bug ... or maybe that's what i would call a feature if i would be a Employee of a bigger Company. ;-)! )

The characteristic of a type e.g. Germans (hans) are usually defined through the constructor (in python : `__init__`) at the moment of the instantiation. This is the point where you define a class to become an object. You could say breath life into an abstract concept (class) by filling it with individual characteristics and becoming an object.

But because every object is an instance of a class they share all some basic characteristic-types and some behavior. This is a major advantage of the object-orientated concept.

To protect the characteristics of each object you encapsulate them - means you try to couple behavior and characteristic and make it hard to manipulate it from outside the object. That's Encapsulation (1)

Answer (score 6):

It is just to initialize the instance's variables.

E.g. create a `crawler` instance with a specific database name (from your example above).

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really understand what that means..in the example above..couldn't the developer just have added in his main code 'left=foo',etc..

Comment: You mean the default values of the function?  `left=None` left will initialized to `None` if upon creation the `left` parameter isn't specified.

Comment: I think its starting to make sense..is it like how you have to predeclare your variables in java "String left" or something? then once its initialized to the class, you can manipulate the values? Its just a bit confusing when compared to functions because I can just send values to functions and don't need to initialize anything in advance.

Comment: @Lostsoul: `left = foo` would work - once. The point of classes is to do something sensible for every different `crawler`. Classes are not functions, nor something that can compare to functions (well, not until you're a lot more advanced and get into functional programming, but that'll just confuse you now). Read my answer for what classes actually are - you're still not getting it.

Answer (score 5):

Following with your **car** example: when you get a car, you just don't get a random car, I mean, you choose the color, the brand, number of seats, etc. And some stuff is also "initialize" without you choosing for it, like number of wheels or registration number.

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, color, brand, number_of_seats):
        self.color = color
        self.brand = brand
        self.number_of_seats = number_of_seats
        self.number_of_wheels = 4
        self.registration_number = GenerateRegistrationNumber()
```

So, in the `__init__` method you defining the attributes of the instance you're creating. So, if we want a blue Renault car, for 2 people, we would initialize or instance of `Car` like:

```
my_car = Car('blue', 'Renault', 2)
```

This way, we are creating an instance of the `Car` class. The `__init__` is the one that is handling our specific attributes (like `color` or `brand`) and its generating the other attributes, like `registration_number`.

- More about [classes in Python](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html)
- More about the [`__init__` method](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__)

Answer (score 5):

It seems like you need to use `__init__` in Python if you want to correctly initialize mutable attributes of your instances.

See the following example:

```
>>> class EvilTest(object):
...     attr = []
... 
>>> evil_test1 = EvilTest()
>>> evil_test2 = EvilTest()
>>> evil_test1.attr.append('strange')
>>> 
>>> print "This is evil:", evil_test1.attr, evil_test2.attr
This is evil: ['strange'] ['strange']
>>> 
>>> 
>>> class GoodTest(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.attr = []
... 
>>> good_test1 = GoodTest()
>>> good_test2 = GoodTest()
>>> good_test1.attr.append('strange')
>>> 
>>> print "This is good:", good_test1.attr, good_test2.attr
This is good: ['strange'] []
```

This is quite different in Java where each attribute is automatically initialized with a new value:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.lang.String;

class SimpleTest
{
    public ArrayList<String> attr = new ArrayList<String>();
}

class Main
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        SimpleTest t1 = new SimpleTest();
        SimpleTest t2 = new SimpleTest();

        t1.attr.add("strange");

        System.out.println(t1.attr + " " + t2.attr);
    }
}
```

produces an output we intuitively expect:

```
[strange] []
```

But if you declare `attr` as `static`, it will act like Python:

```
[strange] [strange]
```

Answer (score 3):

The `__init__` function is setting up all the member variables in the class. So once your bicluster is created you can access the member and get a value back:

```
mycluster = bicluster(...actual values go here...)
mycluster.left # returns the value passed in as 'left'
```

Check out the [Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#a-first-look-at-classes) for some info. You'll want to pick up an book on OO concepts to continue learning.

Answer (score 3):

Classes are objects with attributes (state, characteristic) and methods (functions, capacities) that are specific for that object (like the white color and fly powers, respectively, for a duck).

When you create an instance of a class, you can give it some initial personality (state or character like the name and the color of her dress for a newborn). You do this with `__init__`.

Basically `__init__` sets the instance characteristics automatically when you call `instance = MyClass(some_individual_traits)`.

Answer (score 3):

```
class Dog(object):

    # Class Object Attribute
    species = 'mammal'

    def __init__(self,breed,name):
        self.breed = breed
        self.name = name
```

In above example we use species as a global since it will be always same(Kind of constant you can say). when you call `__init__` method then all the variable inside `__init__` will be initiated(eg:breed,name).

```
class Dog(object):
    a = '12'

    def __init__(self,breed,name,a):
        self.breed = breed
        self.name = name
        self.a= a
```

if you print the above example by calling below like this

```
Dog.a
12

Dog('Lab','Sam','10')
Dog.a
10
```

That means it will be only initialized during object creation. so anything which you want to declare as constant make it as global and anything which changes use  `__init__`

Answer (score 1):

**`__init__()`** can:

- initialize the instance of class.
- be called many time.
- only return `None`.

For example, `Person` class has `__init__()` as shown below:

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        print('"__init__()" is called.')
```

Now, we create and initialize the instance of `Person` class as shown below:

```py
       # Here
obj = Person("John", 27)
```

Then, `__init__()` is called as shown below:

```
"__init__()" is called.
```

Next, we check if `name` and `age` are initialized as shown below:

```py
obj = Person("John", 27)
print(obj.name) # Here
print(obj.age) # Here
```

Then, `name` and `age` are initialized as shown below:

```
"__init__()" is called.
John # Here
27   # Here
```

And, `__init__()` can be called many times as shown below:

```py
obj = Person("John", 27)
print(obj.__init__("Tom", "18")) # Here
print(obj.name)
print(obj.age)
```

Then, `__init__()` is called and the instance of `Person` class is reinitialized and `None` is returned from `__init__()` as shown below:

```
"__init__()" is called.
"__init__()" is called.
None
Tom
18
```

Lastly, if `__init__()` doesn't return `None` and we call `__init__()` as shown below:

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        print('"__init__()" is called.')
        return "Hello" # Here

obj = Person("John", 27) # Here
```

The error below occurs:

> TypeError: **init**() should return None, not 'str'