# How to dynamic loading the field of ChoiceField in form using the database in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms, choicefield

Just like the answer,I want to dynamic Load the database in the choicefield, and i had do this

```
queue = forms.ChoiceField(label=u'queue',choices=((x.que,x.disr) for x in Queue.objects.all()))
```

but it doesn't work ,i must restart the server,the field can be update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call the `__init__` to load the data in form dynamically. For example:

```
class YourForm(forms.Form):
   queue = forms.ChoiceField(label=u'queue')
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(YourForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.fields['queue'].choices = ((x.que,x.disr) for x in Queue.objects.all()))
```

Reason for doing it is that, if you call `__init__` in your form, it initializes an instance of a class and updates the choice list with latest data from database. For detail understanding, check here:[Why do we use __init__ in python classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609153/why-do-we-use-init-in-python-classes)

Comment: @ruddra, what if I only need the value of a single field: If I just change "Queue.ojects.all()" in your answer to "Queue.objects.values_list('region', flat=True).distinct()" then it would report error. Could you please help take a look at my question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33012590/django-init-takes-at-least-2-arguments-for-dynamic-drop-down-list-function. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField) instead of `ChoiceField`: