# django "__init__takes at least 2 arguments" for dynamic drop down list function

Tags: python, django

Regarding the django dynamic drop down list, I made some trials,

**If no dynamic function, it works without problem**

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import input
from result.models import result
from django.contrib.auth.models import User,Group
import Queue

class inputform(forms.ModelForm):

    regionlist = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=result.objects.values('Region').distinct())

class Meta:
    model = input
    fields = ('company', 'Region')
```

**If add the dynamic function like below, there is error of "__Init__takes at least 2 arguments(2 given)**

```
...before are same as above....
class inputform(forms.ModelForm):
    region = forms.ModelChoiceField(label=u'Region')


    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(inputform,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['region'].choices=((x.que,x.disr) for x in result.objects.values('Region').distinct())
```

......below are the same as above one...

**Traceback**

```
Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3 py2.7.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\views\decorators\csrf.py" in wrapped_view
58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\user\XXX\inputform\views.py" in input
13.         form = inputform() #??????
File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\XXX\inputform\forms.py" in __init__
22.         self.fields['region'].choices=((x.que,x.disr) for x in result.objects.values('Region').distinct())
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\forms\fields.py" in _set_choices
851.             value = list(value)
File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\XXX\inputform\forms.py" in <genexpr>
22.         self.fields['region'].choices=((x.que,x.disr) for x in result.objects.values('Region').distinct())

Exception Type: AttributeError at /input
Exception Value: 'dict' object has no attribute 'que'
```

**Second Trial**

```
region = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=None,label=u'region')

def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
    super(InputForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    iquery = Result.objects.values_list('region', flat=True).distinct()
    iquery_choices = [('', '')] + [(region,region)  for region in iquery]
```

I think now it is dic, but it still reports the same error. Please help thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You must pass queryset to your [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#fields-which-handle-relationships). From docs:

> For more complex uses, you can specify `queryset=None` when declaring the form field and then populate the queryset in the form’s `__init__()` method:

```
class inputform(forms.ModelForm):
    region = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=None, label=u'Region')


    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(inputform,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['region'].choices=((x['Region'].que,x['Region'].disr) for x in dupont.objects.values('Region').distinct())
```

Comment: thank you a lot. But I still get the same error. I put the error trackback in the above post.

Comment: You got this error because values method return dict(not object). Try this self.fields['region'].choices=((x['Region'].que,x['Region'].disr) for x in dupont.objects.values('Region').distinct())

Comment: @Andrea Corbellini, I tried Dima's above two solutions but still got the same error, and also I updated another trial in my question, also same error. Could you please help pinpoint the solution, thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't get this error, because in your Second Trial you are using values_list with flat parameter and it return list not dict. What problems you has and what is region in your Result model?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in two of the following ways(assuming region is FK with `input` model):

**First:**

```
class inputform(forms.ModelForm):

    regionlist = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=None)

    def region_list(self):
       # This method returns a list consists of primary keys of Region.
       return [x['Region'] for x in result.objects.values('Region').distinct()]

    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['regionlist'].queryset = Region.objects.filter(id__in=self.region_list())
```

In region model, add this method to display `que` and `disr` to display them in choice field.

```
class Region(models.Model):
    ...
    def __str__(self):
       return '{0}, {1}'.format(self.que, self.disr)
```

**Second:**

```
class inputform(forms.ModelForm):
        regionlist = forms.ChoiceField()
        def region_list(self):
           # This method returns a list consists of primary keys of Region.
           return [x['Region'] for x in result.objects.values('Region').distinct()]

        def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
             super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

             self.fields['regionlist'].choices = [(Region.objects.get(id=x).que, User.objects.get(id=x).disr) for x in self.region_list()]

        def clean_regionlist(self):
            # returns region object
            return Region.objects.get(pk=self.cleaned_data['regionlist'])
```