# Display/print the applicable __init__ method

Tags: python, methods

Lawrence Benson points out that if you don't include an `__init__` in your class, then it will inherit from a superclass by default [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32522621/5559588).

[Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects) supports this when stating that, "a class **may** define a special method named `__init__()`."

Is there any way to print/display a description of the `__init__()` or `__new__()` methods that apply to a particular class? Meaning - in the interpreter, can I run a command that will return them?

I've tried to run everything I can find in `__dir__`, to no avail:

```
>>>__dir__ 
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'drive']
```

Comment: I'm not sure this answers your question, but if you use `help` you can get information on the methods. For instance if you want info on `int`'s `__init__` method you could do `help(int.__init__)`

Comment: What do you mean by description? The docstring? If so, why `__doc__` doesn't suit your needs?

Comment: Additionally using `__doc__` will get just the string. `>>> int.__init__.__doc__`
`'Initialize self.  See help(type(self)) for accurate signature.'`

Comment: @Bit - I'm trying to get a printout of the init method that was used to initialize the subclass. It could be a method that was written specifically for the subclass, or it could be the init method that was inherited from a superclass. Either way, I want to be able to see the contents of the initialization method that was used.

Comment: @AFK: so you want to see the source code?

Comment: @MartijnPieters If this is a duplicate, where's the original version? @AFK, you can access an instance's `__init__` doc string with `instance.__init__.__doc__`

Comment: @MartijnPieters That would probably fry my brain, but maybe so.

Comment: @AFK: *I want to be able to see the contents of the initialization method that was used.*; that's the source code.

Comment: @CoryMadden Your suggestion gets me really close to what I was looking for Cory. When I use print(subclass.__init__), I get this back: <function superclass.__init__ at 0x1022602f0> --- this tells me which init module is being applied to the subclass, and that's the information that I seek. Thank you!

Comment: Great! you're welcome.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - thanks for that too. I'll dig in on the source code a bit to get a better understanding.