# Can't call function Python

Tags: python, function

Here is my code that calls the `__init__` of `Game_Events` class:

```
class Game_Events(object):
    def __init__(self, DoSetup):
        if DoSetup == "yes":
            print "Done"

GE = Game_Events()
GE.__init__("no")
```

But when ever I run the code I get:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `GE = Game_Events("no")`, you might also be better of giving DoSetup a default value `DoSetup=False`

Comment: This may provide you with more information on init: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609153/why-do-we-use-init-in-python-classes

Answer (score 4):

`Game_Events.__init__()` is called *for you*, you don't call it directly. It is called when you create an instance:

```
Game_Events()  # calls Game_Events.__init__(newly_created_instance)
```

Because you didn't pass in an argument to that call, things break. Pass in `'no'` to that call:

```
GE = Game_Events('no')  # calls Game_Events.__init__(newly_created_instance, 'no')
```

Answer (score 0):

**init** functions are called while creating an instance for that class only.

Try this:

```
class Game_Events(object):
    def __init__(self, DoSetup):
        if DoSetup == "yes":
            print "Done"

GE = Game_Events("no")

GE = Game_Events("yes") # output will be yes
```