# I am trying to understand class and function and can't seem to figure out what is wrong with my code

Tags: python, oop

Calculating the area of a triangle

```
class area:

    def traingle(self,height,length):
        self.height=height
        self.length=length

    def calculate(self,maths):
        self.maths= (self.height)*(self.length)*(0.5)

    def answer(self):
        print 'Hello, the aswer is %i'%self.maths

first= area()

first.traingle(4,5)

first.calculate

print first.answer
```

Comment: So what is wrong with your code? Do you get an error? Do you get an unexpected result? What is it?

Comment: <bound method classarea.answer of <__main__.classarea instance at 0x101978a28>>

Comment: `first.calculate` is just an attribute access, you don't call the method. Same with `first.answer`

Comment: also the maths argument is redundant

Comment: `Triangle` should be a class. The `area()` method should `return` a value.

Comment: @Mixone initialisers are not mandatory in both old-style and new-style classes.

Comment: in calculate i mean

Comment: @EliKorvigo true that, was just the first thing that stood out haha (also if he/she is learning the use of init is recommended as a learning tool according to my professor from my first year)

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
import math


class Triangle:

    def __init__(self, height, length):
        self.height = height
        self.length = length

    def calculate(self):
        return (self.height) * (self.length) * (0.5)

    def answer(self):
        print 'Hello, the aswer is %.2f' % self.calculate()

first = Triangle(4, 5)
first.answer()
```

Remember, to call a method you need to use parenthesis, when you're doing `first.answer` you're not executing your method, instead you should be doing `first.answer()`

Another different solution for this type of problem could be something like this:

```
import math


class Triangle:

    def __init__(self, height, length):
        self.height = height
        self.length = length

    def area(self):
        return (self.height) * (self.length) * (0.5)


class Quad:

    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def area(self):
        return self.width * self.height


for index, obj in enumerate([Triangle(4, 5), Quad(2, 3)]):
    print 'Area for {0} {1} = {2:.2f}'.format(obj.__class__, index, obj.area())
```

In any case, make sure you go through some of the available [python tutorials](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm) out there in order to understand all the concepts first ;-)

Comment: Also, the area may not be an integer.  Use `print 'Hello, the aswer is %.2f' % self.calculate()`

Comment: and PEP8 says classes are Camel Case

Comment: @BPL why did you use %.2f

Comment: is   ' def __init__' absolutely neccesary?

Comment: @gurkha_dawg [why-do-we-use-init-in-python-classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609153/why-do-we-use-init-in-python-classes)