# Calling a variable from another method in the same class

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop

**My scenario**

I only have one class with two methods. In the first method I store values in a variable. In the second method I try to call these variables

```
class UpdateTallysheet(Page):

    def confirme_status_capture_exp_value(self):

        self.select_dropdown_value(EventsLocators.STATUS, "8")
        value_1 = self.find_element(EventsLocators.EXAM_EXP_VALUE).get_attribute("value")
        value_2 = self.find_element(EventsLocators.PANO_EXP_VALUE).get_attribute("value")
        value_3 = self.find_element(EventsLocators.TREATMENT_EXP_VALUE).get_attribute("value")

        self.find_element(EventsLocators.SAVE_BUTTON).click()
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, AUTOCOMPLETE_TIMEOUT).until(
            EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.CLASS_NAME, "success"), 'Event updated successfully'))
        self.find_element(EventsLocators.TALLYSHEET_LINK).click()

    def fill_date(self):

        self.select_current_date(EventsLocators.DATE_RECEIVED, EventsLocators.CURRENT_DATE)
        self.select_current_date(EventsLocators.DATE_COMPLETED, EventsLocators.CURRENT_DATE)
        print self.value_1
```

**My error**

> AttributeError: 'UpdateTallysheet' object has no attribute 'value_1'

How can I use the variable `value_1` in another method?

Answer (score 6):

You need to set it to an instance variable by using `self`:

```
class UpdateTallysheet(Page):
    def confirme_status_capture_exp_value(self):
        self.select_dropdown_value(EventsLocators.STATUS, "8")
        self.value_1 = self.find_element(EventsLocators.EXAM_EXP_VALUE).get_attribute("value")
        self.value_2 = self.find_element(EventsLocators.PANO_EXP_VALUE).get_attribute("value")
        self.value_3 = self.find_element(EventsLocators.TREATMENT_EXP_VALUE).get_attribute("value")
```

Then you can use it in another method by using `self.value_1`

Comment: Worked Will. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to help!  Also, an `__init__()` method may not be necessary, but I find it helps with keeping organized.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609153/why-do-we-use-init-in-python-classes

Comment: I'm having the same problem again, see my code here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/61e2a757b451871867964966a36940d5 and I'm getting the error `AttributeError: 'CreateContractor' object has no attribute 'firstname'` Any idea?

Comment: It's hard to say with no context, at first glace that code seems fine.  If I were going to guess, I would say something to do with `fake.first_name()` or possibly with the order in which you are calling these methods. Open a new question and post not just the class, but the code that uses the class as well.