# What does __init__ and self do in Python programming?

Tags: python-2.7

I'm starting to learn Python from Learn Python The Hard way by Zed A. Shaw. 
But I'm having a hard time to understand what init function in a class does and what is self? Please help me understand this.

Comment: A class is sort of like a blueprint. Say you have a car class, the class is the blueprint to build the car. `__init__` is the initializer which is called when an object, or instance of a car is created. So, the class tells you how to build it and what it will have (x windows and y seats) and the object is an instance of the car itself. `self` is just a name (can be anything else) that refers to the current instance, or itself

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python \_\_init\_\_ and self what do they do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625083/python-init-and-self-what-do-they-do)

Comment: So the properties of a class (say car) like color , number of wheels should be defined in the __init__ function? Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

___init____ initializes an instance of a class or an object.

Refer these links for more info:

[Why do we use __init__ in python classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609153/why-do-we-use-init-in-python-classes)

[What is the purpose of self?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-self)

Hope this helps.

**Edit**

Like this:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, Wheels, colour):
        self.Wheels = Wheels
        self.colour = colour

x = Car(4, "Red")
y = Car(4, "White")
```

Comment: This answer is highly incomplete and vague. If there are duplicates please flag as such...

Comment: So the properties of a class (say car) like color , number of wheels should be defined in the __init__ function? Right?

Comment: See the edited answer. @SamarSrivastava

Comment: Thank you very much, Ambrish!