# what difference does __init__() make?

Tags: python, init

I am fairly new to learning programming and starting with Python. I have read on the utility of using **init**() function in classes and understand it somewhat. However, I am still a little confused and hope someone could clarify that.

So I have two set of preliminary codes which give the same output, but one uses **init**(). The first one is as follows:

```
class person:
    def who(self, name):
        print('I am', name)

name=str('Joe')
person().who(name)
```

The second one is here:

```
class person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def who(self):
        print('I am', self.name)

p = person('Joe')
p.who()
```

My basic question is what would I miss in general case of my code (may be more complex at some stage) if I take the first approach and not the second one Or what I would I gain with the second approach.

Thanks!

PS: My question is not what **init**() means (although that is related and certainly of interest to me), but why making use of **init**() essentially makes the code better.

Comment: You don't need `p.who()` for the second approach. Just use `p.name`; there is no need to create the `who()` method at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do we use \_\_init\_\_ in python classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609153/why-do-we-use-init-in-python-classes)

Comment: the `__init__` method is a _class constructor_. Its used when you need to initialize your class with certain variables. But as @roganjosh has already mentioned, why do you have the `who()` method at all? The easiest way to create the class in your example would be to remove the who method all together, and simply do `print(p.name)`.

Comment: Have you seen this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609153/why-do-we-use-init-in-python-classes

Comment: But `print(p.name)` doesn't print `"I am " + p.name` :) I suspect the `who` method is just a contrived example @ChristianDean

Comment: @DavidZemens Well yes, I guess your correct :P So perhaps a `__repr__()` would be a better option then.

Comment: @DavidZemens I think this is a case that contrived examples obscure actual functionality. I realised my own error after I posted the comment. That said, I don't think there's a good way to bridge from tutorial to actual use :( The middle-ground is hard to find.

Comment: Thanks! You guys are right and removing the who() function in second works. I actually read the thread suggested above. And it is really helpful in making things clearer. However once I remove the who() function, it seems the two code are pretty similar, which makes me think why use __init__() at all?

Comment: @Yogesh then re-read the other link. "who" is an instance property, not a class property. Or at least it *should* be.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are missing the main purpose of classes: to provide a cohesive and modular group of data and functionality.

You created a class person, so which information does a person hold?
Her name, birthday, and gender, for example.

This is what `__init__()` is for, it is a built-in method used to initialize a person after being born (i.e. when being *instantiated*).
For example, after creating a person you HAVE to give it a name, a birthday and a gender. Hence, `__init__()` enforces that persons are always initialized in a valid state. This means that you can go to the street and ask any person you encounter for her name, while being sure that everyone has a one.

As for your second example, what makes more sense, to ask for an unknown's person name, or to tell her what her name should be?

Comment: Is this your own analogy or part of a broader tutorial that can be linked to for future questions?

Comment: Thanks @Pablo! That is definitely helpful. Am I right in saying that __init__() adds to better (more efficient?) functionality of the code in the sense it initializes all the attributes (hope that is the right terminology?) like name, gender, birthday and so on. We can conveniently call upon them later in the code. Where as in the first example I will have to create a separate function for name, gender, birthday and so on. I apologize in advance if I am dumbing things down here.