# What happens when your class does not explicitly define an __init__ method?

Tags: python, class

How does the quality of my code gets affected if I don't use `__init__` method in python? A simple example would be appreciated.

Comment: quality is a word depends on you. Without init there can be quality code but you understand why constructors are important in any class (generalised to every class in every language)

Comment: I can't see any constructive way to answer this that isn't just a broad-ranging discussion of OO principles. Maybe you could try writing some non-toy classes with and without using `__init__`, see what you think the differences are, and ask a question about your real code if you need to?

Comment: BTW - the _title_ is a perfectly answerable question. The bit about the quality of your code is the part that makes it over-broad. That's a _huge_ discussion.

Answer (score 3):

*Short answer*; nothing happens.

*Long answer*; if you have a class `B`, which inherits from a class `A`, and if `B` has no `__init__` method defined, then the parent's (in this case, `A`) `__init__` is invoked.

```
In [137]: class A:
     ...:     def __init__(self):
     ...:         print("In A")
     ...:         

In [138]: class B(A): pass

In [139]: B()
In A
Out[139]: <__main__.B at 0x1230a5ac8>
```

If `A` has no predecessor, then the almighty superclass `object`'s `__init__` is invoked, which does nothing.

You can view class hierarchy by querying the dunder `__mro__`.

```
In [140]: B.__mro__
Out[140]: (__main__.B, __main__.A, object)
```

Also see [Why do we use __init__ in Python classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609153/why-do-we-use-init-in-python-classes) for some context as to *when and where* its usage is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Its not a matter of quality here, in `Object-oriented-design` which python supports, `__init__` is way to supply data when an object is created first. In `OOPS`, this is called a `constructor`. In other words **A constructor is a method which prepares a valid object**.

There are design patters on large projects are build that rely on the constructor feature provided by python. Without this they will not function,

**for e.g.**

- You want to keep track of every object that is created for a class, now you need a method which is executed every time a object is created, hence the **constructor**.
- Other useful example for a constructor is lets say you want to create a `customer` object for a Bank. Now a customer for a bank will must have an `account number`, so basically you have to set a rule for a valid customer object for a Bank hence the constructor.