# Use Class with custom statement in Python

Tags: python

I have a class in Python:

```
class CursorSetPagination(CursorPagination):
    page_size = 1
    page_size_query_param = 'per_page'
    ordering = '-posted_on'
```

I want to call this class with change statement `page_size = 5` in it. I tried with this code:

`paginator = CursorSetPagination(page_size = 5)`

It doesn't work. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `__init__` for it.  Refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609153/why-do-we-use-init-in-python-classes) for better understanding.

```
class CursorSetPagination(CursorPagination):
    def __init__(self, page_size=1, page_size_query_param='per_page', ordering):
        self.page_size = page_size
        self.page_size_query_param = 'page_size_query_param '
        self.ordering = ordering
```

You can reset the parameters used in `__init__` this as below:

```
paginator = CursorSetPagination(page_size = 5)
```

Comment: Socialpath. Thanks. I will pick you best. But I dont know why people dislike my question. Maybe this is a stupid question right?

Comment: No clue why people are downvoting your question. I think this question is genuine.