# How do functions work in cogs (discord.py)?

Tags: discord, discord.py

An error occurs using this code it says bot is not defined. I don't understand cogs that much but I understand a bit of classes too. I wanted to know how functions work in a cog and how variables are assigned like `guildstats = ...` below.

This is my code: (I am trying to make a database using the discord bot in a guild. The code works without using cogs but I wanted it to be easier to debug any errors so I went for cogs.)

```py
class Boot(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    guildstats = pd.read_excel('DiscordStats.xlsx',sheet_name=0)
    userstats = pd.read_excel('DiscordStats.xlsx',sheet_name=1)

    def dataframe_to_excel(df1 = guildstats, df2 = userstats):
        with pd.ExcelWriter('DiscordStats.xlsx', mode = 'w') as writer:
            df1.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name = 'GuildStats')
            df2.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name = 'UserStats')

    def guildstats_writer():
        guild_row_data = []
        for guild in self.bot.guilds:
            if '\''+str(guild.id) not in guildstats['GuildID'].to_list():
                guild_row_data.append([guild.name,'\''+str(guild.id),'','',False])
            else:
                pass
        guild_row = pd.DataFrame(guild_row_data,columns = guildstats.columns.to_list())
        guildstats1 = guildstats.append(guild_row,ignore_index=True)
        Boot.dataframe_to_excel(df1=guildstats1)

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        Boot.guildstats_writer(self)
        await sbot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="for MeepMop ~help"))
        print(f'{bot.user} is connected to the following guild:')
        for guild in bot.guilds:
            print(f'{guild.name} (id: {guild.id})')

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Boot(bot))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to call the variable **bot** when you never defined it, your program has no idea what the variable "bot" is, try changing all the times you called bot to instead call **self.bot** instead

For example your on_ready function should look like this:

```py
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        Boot.guildstats_writer(self)
        await self.bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="for MeepMop ~help"))
        print(f'{self.bot.user} is connected to the following guild:')
        for guild in self.bot.guilds:
            print(f'{guild.name} (id: {guild.id})')
```

Comment: Oh, so what is the use of the `def __init__` in the beginning?

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609153/why-do-we-use-init-in-python-classes, it should answer your question.