# What's the difference between the following ways of initializing attributes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

```
# case 1
class Foo():
    a = 'spam'

>>> x = Foo()
>>> x.a
'spam'

#case 2
class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 'spam'

>>> y = Foo()
>>> y.a
'spam'

#case 3
class Foo():
    pass
>>> z = Foo()
>>> z.a = 'spam'
```

1. All objects that I instantiate based on `Foo`, have the `a` attribute in cases 1 and 2. So what's the difference? Why define the attributes within the `__init__()` method as in case 2 over case 1. Other than the former more logical and closer-to-reality style of organizing the code (e.g. [reasoning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8609238) that the `class` `Dog` doesn't have any `color` *per se*, but a particular instance of that `Dog`, say `scooby` does, so it makes more sense to define the attribute `color` within the `__init__()` method.), is there any other reason?
2. I see the advantage of cases 1 and 2 over case 3. But when would I need to assign an attribute to an object like in case 3?

Comment: Case 1 creates a _class_ attribute, case 2 creates an _instance_ attribute. With an immutable value like a string it's hard to tell the difference, but there is one. Case 3 means you can easily make a mistake and have a "Foo" that lacks the attribute entirely.

Comment: In addition to the first comment. You can access `a` in Case 1 without creating an instance of Foo. You can use it like `Foo.a` because its an class attribute

Comment: @jonrsharpe can you please elaborate further, maybe in terms of a memory model?

Comment: With a mutable value: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1680528/3001761

Comment: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/articles/class-attributes-vs-instance-attributes-in-python